What is the Shulchan Aruch HaZohar?
I was browsing through the website of Seforim Center when I came across something I'd never heard of that didn't have much of a description, the 12-volume "Shulchan Aruch HaZohar," covering everything except Orach Chayim.
One can assume that this is a sequel of sorts to Kaf HaChayim, a comprehensive kabbalistic commentary of Orach Chayim, but since I found no information on Shulchan Aruch HaZohar with a Google search, I figured it would be better to ask than to assume.

From what I can gather from the introduction, it's a series of books that collect halachic teachings in Zoharic texts, with added commentary, by Rabbi Avraham Abish Tzeinwirt. The books can be accessed via Otzar Hachochmah. From what I can tell, it has everything except Choshen Mishpat (it does have Orach Chaim).
